# Exporting high resolution topigraphical image?

Tags: html, maps

I'd like to export [this topigraphical map](http://toposvalbard.npolar.no/) at high resolution. The one Google Maps provides is very low detail and lacks necessary information. The aforementioned website hosts a topographical map of Svalbard that is absolutely spectacular — but there aren't any options to download the full image. I had hoped there might be an option to extract it via HTML. I would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve]. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

That map comes from an arcgis map service, which offers lots of formats and ways to access the data. See, e.g. http://barentsz.npolar.no/arcgis/rest/services/Basisdata_Intern/NP_TopoSvalbard/MapServer .

It has even tools for exporting big images, e.g. http://barentsz.npolar.no/arcgis/rest/services/Basisdata_Intern/NP_TopoSvalbard/MapServer/export?bbox=369976%2C8221306%2C878234%2C9010718&size=600%2C800

Comment: I've used that tool before, but it won't allow me to export anything beyond 3072x4096. Is there an alternative you can think of?